# WPF Bind a List<List<object>> to a ItemsControl which holds ItemControls as Items

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want to show a List with items where each item contains several items.
I tried to realize this with ItemsControls so that the ItemsControl on top is bound to the List that holds several Lists.
The itemtemplate of the ItemsControl on top contains a Label with a Style which defines that the label should hold a textbox and a ItemsControl.
The textbox should be bound to an property of the list and the ItemsControl should be bound to the list itself. This ItemsControl again has an textblock as itemtemplate which Text and Visibility-property is bound to properties of the Items which are in the lower list.

The ItemsControl on top:

```wpf
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../Styles/AlternativeAdressBoxStyle.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid Margin="10,0,10,10">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black"
            BorderThickness="1">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AlternativeAdressLabelList}"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Style="{StaticResource AlternativeAdressBoxStyle}"
                           DataContext="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

The Style-file:

```wpf
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">


    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="../Styles/LabelRowTextBlockStyle.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <Style x:Key="AlternativeAdressBoxStyle" 
           TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Label">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                       Text="{Binding Path=.AcountingArea}"/>
                            <Border Grid.Row="1"
                        Margin="20"
                        BorderBrush="Black"
                        BorderThickness="1">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                                   Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                   Grid.Row="0"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                                    <ItemsControl Grid.Column="0"
                                                  Grid.Row="1"
                                                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=.}">
                                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource LabelRowTextBlockStyle}"/>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

                                    </ItemsControl>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The TextBlock-Style:

```wpf
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style x:Key="LabelRowTextBlockStyle"
           TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Margin"
                Value="0,5"/>
        <Setter Property="Height"
                Value="20"/>
        <Setter Property="Width"
                Value="200"/>
        <Setter Property="Text"
                Value="{Binding Content}"/>
        <Setter Property="Visibility"
                Value="{Binding Visibility}"/>
    </Style>    
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The property to which the ItemsControl is bound:

```cs
    public List<AlternativeAdressLetterLabel> AlternativeAdressLabelList
            {
                get { return this._alternativeAdressLabelList; }
                set { this.SetProperty( ref this._alternativeAdressLabelList, value); }
            }

The list-class which fundamental inherits from List<LabelRow>

<!-- language: c# -->

    public class AlternativeAdressLetterLabel : DbConnectedLabelRowList
    {

        #region fields

        private string _sNumber;
        private Dictionary<int, string> _acountingArea;

        #endregion

        #region properties

        public string SNumber
        {
            get { return this._sNumber; }
            set
            {
                this._sNumber = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public Dictionary<int, string> AcountingArea
        {
            get { return this._acountingArea; }
            set
            {
                this._acountingArea = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        #endregion
```

and finally the properties of the class which is hold by `AlternativeAdressLetterLabel`

```cs
    public string Content
    {
        get { return this._content; }
        set { SetProperty(ref this._content, value); }
    }

    public string Visibility
    {
        get { return this._visibility; }
        set { SetProperty(ref this._visibility, value); }
    }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: So what is your question? Anyway, "the label should hold a textbox and a ItemsControl" is certainly the wrong approach. Put the TextBox and the inner ItemsControl into the ItemTemplate of the outer ItemsControl. XAML elements can easily be nested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve what you want without having to modify any ControlTemplates.

Within the Resources of your UserControl, you can define 2 `DataTemplate` resources which define how each item in your `ItemsControl` will be displayed. For example:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <DataTemplate x:Key="LabelRowTemplate" DataType="{x:Type model:LabelRow}">
    <TextBlock Margin="0,5" Height="20" Width="200" Text="{Binding Content}" />
  </DataTemplate>
  <DataTemplate x:Key="AlternativeAddressTemplate" DataType="{x:Type model:AlternativeAddressLetterLabel}">
    <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.1*" />
        <RowDefinition />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding AccountingArea}" />
      <Border Grid.Row="1" Margin="20" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
        <StackPanel>
          <TextBlock Text="<Whatever text goes here>" />
          <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LabelRowTemplate}" />
        </StackPanel>
      </Border>
    </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Note that the second `DataTemplate` references the first `DataTemplate`. The second `DataTemplate` defines how you want the items in your "outer" list to be displayed--a `TextBox` on top of an `ItemsControl`. The template is referred to by its `Key` property as a `StaticResource`.

Also note that in the code above, it is assuming a declaration of a namespace called *model* pointing to where your classes are defined. e.g.,

```
xmlns:model="clr-namespace:MyAwesomeCompany.MyAwesomeApp.Model"
```

With those `DataTemplate` resources defined, you can declare your "outer" list `ItemsControl` as follows:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AlternativeAddressLabelList}" ItemTemplate={StaticResource AlternativeAddressTemplate}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

That should get you on your way to achieving the layout you are looking for.

One additional note--if these lists of lists are added to dynamically, those changes will not automatically show up in the view. If you want that, look into collections that provide CollectionChanged events such as `ObservableCollection<T>`.